# Split vector into group by sequence

Tags: r, split

I have a vector of years

```
a = c(0.2,1.4,1.8,4.2,6.7,6.8,7.4)
```

I want to cut this vector into a list such that all a[i] in one year is an element of the list.

e.g a will get cut into

```
$`1`
[1]  0.2
$`2`
[1]  1.4,1.8
$`3`
[1] 4.2
```

and so on .....

Comment: You want `as.list(a)`?

Comment: No, that will not club 1.4 and 1.8 and 6.7 and 6.8

Comment: How do you define a **year**?

Comment: 0-1 is 1st year 1-2 is second year and so on. So 0.2 falls in year one. 1.4 and 1.8 falls in year 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `floor()` function to round down and use that as your splitting rule, i.e.

```
split(a, floor(a))
```

which gives,

```
$`0`
[1] 0.2

$`1`
[1] 1.4 1.8

$`4`
[1] 4.2

$`6`
[1] 6.7 6.8

$`7`
[1] 7.4
```